# MS Word - Possible to Add Embedded Document?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop, openxml, office-addins

I'm in the process of exploring the possibilities of Word VSTO add-in. Using a combination of custom task pane(s), a custom ribbon and a series of dialog boxes or forms I can collection information from the user. However, what I can figure out is where I can persist this information within the document.  A docx is made of a series of individual files, how do I add my file within the cab as well?  Storing the custom info outside of the document is not an option, it must travel with the document itself.

Thanks,

**Update** : If I use custom xml parts per the solution mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608612.aspx then it appears to me that the xml data is visible to the user. See screen shot.  The user should not be able to browse data that my add-in is storeing - not because it's senstitive but because it makes no sense for them to see and interact with a bunch of serialized class data.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your custom information inside the document using so called Custom XML Parts. This information is stored within the document.

Here is an example how to add a Custom XML Part to your document:

[How to: Add Custom XML Parts to Documents by Using VSTO Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608612.aspx)

Comment: Please see my edits above which mention your suggestion.  I have tried this and on the surface this seems like to would work fine.  However I don't want this xml visible to the users.  My xml would store serialized state information and make no sense to drag out onto the canvas.  Is there a way to mark this as hidden?

Comment: Default installations don't have the Developer Tab enabled. Basically -ALL- information is available through the Developer Tab, if it is not behind a button you can still access all document parts using the Macros and/or VBA option (remember that even without Word they can access the information simply by renaming the document to .zip).

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly helps as we consider this as a viable option for us.  Definitely a super helpful answer though.